# Linux performance of loading shared objects

Tags: linux, dlopen

I have a design decision to make regarding how I load shared objects (.so) files.

I will ultimately benchmark my options, but I would like to get the feedback of my fellow stackoverflow colleagues.

Normally stackoverflow wants one question per "Question", but these questions are so strongly related I am putting them in one "Question".

Right now I have many (1000-4000) .so files and each .so file has one symbol that is resolved with dlsym().  I have many processes that share these .so files.  Each of these processes are forked from a common parent.

Here are some questions I have about the performance of loading .so files using dlopen/dlsym/dlclose:

1. How much advantage would there be to merge the 1000 .so files into one .so file?  (e.g. there would be 1 dlopen() and many dlsym()s.) (consider that only need 20 or so .so files are needed in any one process).
2. If a .so file is loaded into one process does it load faster into another process?  (e.g. Does it use Copy On Write such that the two processes that separately did a dlopen actually share physical memory for the .so?).
3. How much advantage would there be to loading the .so files in the parent process before the fork?  (e.g.: the fork would just need to duplicate the page table for the .so rather than load it).
4. Any other factors I should consider when trying to benchmark my options?

Comment: Did you ever do that benchmark?

Comment: You do not want to use fork() for anything else than doing an execvp() immediately after. Most Linux freaks might tell you differently. Using fork() for something else than doing execvp() is especially not documented when multiple threads are being used. A shared library loaded into the parent process does not survive the execvp() in the child process.